# How to denote the union operation of $n$ weighted graphs correctly?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, notation, self-learning

Lets say you have two weighted graphs $G_1=(V_1, E_1, d_1), G_2=(V_2, E_2, d_2)$ which do not have common vertices. You would like to union $G_1$ and $G_2$ by adding new edges (for instance, by adding the one new edge only). You can denote the union by $$G_1 + G_2 = (V_1 \cup V_2, E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E' \cup V_1 \times V_2 \cup V_2 \times V_1, d_1 \cup d_2 \cup d'), $$ where $E'$ is the set of new (added) edges, and $d'$ is the set of weights corresponded to added edges and defined by some rules (for instance, all elements are constant).

**Question.** How to expand the formula on the common case when you have $n$ graphs: $G_1=(V_1, E_1, d_1), G_2=(V_2, E_2, d_2), \ldots, G_n=(V_n, E_n, d_n)$?

I have tried to write:

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^n G_i=G_1+G_2+\ldots G_n=\\(V_1 \cup V_2 \cup \ldots \cup V_n, \\E_1 \cup E_2 \cup \ldots E_n \cup E' \cup \color{red}{V_1 \times V_2 \times  \ldots \times V_n \cup V_n \times V_{n-1} \times \ldots \times V_1}, \\d_1 \cup d_2 \cup \ldots \cup d_n \cup d').$$

I'm not sure in the red part $V_1 \times V_2 \times  \ldots \times V_n \cup V_n \times V_{n-1} \times \ldots \times V_1$.